# How to detect a browser using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with a css which is implement by the jQuery, css is work fine in mozilla but not in chrome so need to make a changes in css according to the browser BUT in JQUERY

Anyone help me to get the browser whether it is firefox,chrome or any other.

```
 if ($browserFirefox) {
    ....code 
    $('#test').css("margin-top","10%");
 }
 if ($browserChorme) {
   code goes here
 }
 if ($browserXYZ) {
   code goes here
 }
```

Comment: Ask instead question regarding `css is work fine in mozilla but not in chrome`?! What is the issue with `margin-top: 10%;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are facing problems, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 10):

Use navigator.userAgent for browser information, like:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do changes in css with differente browsers ,you can follow blow codes easily

```
if Webkit (Safari/Chrome) {

 #myDIV {margin-top:-3px}

 } else if (Firefox) {

 #myDIV {margin-top:0px}

 } else { // IE and other browsers

  #myDIV {margin-top:1px}
 }
```

Although in level of Jquery you can use jquery.browser.Take a look at this
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

For a better use of the answer of @Nikhil Butani.
Happy coding ;)

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("NET") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Edge") >= 0) {
    //code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/).

```
if($.browser.mozzila){
}
```

However, I strongly recommended you try to come up with a cross-browser solution. User-agent sniffing is not a recommended approach as it can break easily(think multiple versions of same browser).

See [Downsides of using the navigator object / user-agent sniffing for detecting IE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145067/downsides-of-using-the-navigator-object-user-agent-sniffing-for-detecting-ie-v) and [Browser Detection (and What to Do Instead)](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/)

**Update**
*For jQuery > 1.9*

> This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through
>   the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to **use feature detection instead**.

Comment: No, this has been removed from jq 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You might be as well fixing the issue in your css rather than with scripting. Check out http://browserhacks.com/ for browser specific targeting information. You can still use jquery to put a particular class on it, but then declare things differently in your css

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the [jQuery.browser property](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    ....code 
    $('#test').css("margin-top","10%");
 }
 if ($.browser.webkit) {
   code goes here
 }
 if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   code goes here
 }
```

Should do the work.